# A NotFound method is invoked twice due to my settings in Web.config and Global.asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I have an MVC5 application. In the config file, I have set the following:

```sh
    <httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <clear/>
      <error statusCode="400" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/BadRequest" />
      <error statusCode="403" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Forbidden" />
      <error statusCode="404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/NotFoundFromWebConfig" />
      <error statusCode="500" responseMode="ExecuteURL" path="/Error/Index" />
    </httpErrors>
```

I also in the Global.asax.cs file in the Application_Error method, handle the error:

```sh
     Response.TrySkipIisCustomErrors = true;
     HttpContext.Current?.Response.Redirect("~/Error/NotFound", true);
```

Now, when I hit a controller for example mysite/contactus/blah, I see that the NotFound method is invoked twice.

I have tried to disable one of these two but I get different issues when I do that. For example if I remove the one in the config file, when 404 happens, I get that ugly black and red page. If I remove the second one, I get redirected to a blank page.

Can someone please help? Thank you.

Comment: If your project is 100% ASP.NET MVC (without any `.aspx` files) then you don't need to implement `Application-Error`.

Comment: Also, check you don't have any IIS URL Rewrite rules (`<rewrite>`) that are triggering a secondary request.

Comment: Have you verified that your application isn't sending any 3xx redirections to the error page? (i.e. `GET /foo -> HTTP 301 /bar -> GET /bar -> HTTP 404`).

Comment: @Dai Thank you for your reply. Yes, I decided to remove the error handling from the Global.asax and consequently don't clear the server and context error. I also had a catch all route in my routeconfig file which I removed since I already restrict my routes by a condition. So I believe it should be good now. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per conversation above,  I removed the error handling from the Global.asax andI also had a catch all route in my routeconfig file which I removed since I already restrict my routes by a condition. This fixed the issue.